# Docker container logs not rolling

Tags: docker

I run my docker container with log-rotation:

```
Docker: Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build 7392c3b/17.03.1-ce
Platform: Linux version 4.9.32-15.41.amzn1.x86_64 (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) )
```

`docker inspect`

```
"HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {
                    "max-file": "4",
                    "max-size": "250m"
                }
            },
```

But my container logs are still way bigger:

```
 rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17M Nov 21 17:54 ServiceBackend-24f1d4f56ab0-stdouterr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4G Nov 22 09:59 ServiceBackend-3289df17fc6c-stdouterr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18K Nov 21 17:18 ServiceBackend-3dd32dd72e4c-stdouterr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67M Nov 21 18:05 ServiceBackend-43bafc60b140-stdouterr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 499M Nov 21 17:05 ServiceBackend-6afbcf5dcb0a-stdouterr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 129M Nov 21 17:53 ServiceBackend-c76ee4033c5a-stdouterr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 731M Nov 21 17:51 ServiceBackend-d11ddbded99c-stdouterr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 137M Nov 21 17:56 ServiceBackend-d66851d8ebf8-stdouterr.log
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What platform and version of docker?

Comment: What logs are those? They don't appear to be named correctly for the json logs.

Comment: Where are you seeing those logs? They are not named correctly for Docker's json logs.

Comment: /var/log/containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs you are looking at are generated by something other than docker's json logging driver and are therefore not maintained by docker's log rotation options. The /var/log/containers directory is not part of a normal docker CE install. Docker rotates the json logs in `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log*`. Using the following test:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --log-opt max-file=3 --log-opt max-size=1k debian /bin/bash
root@e6300962b9ff:/# i=0      
root@e6300962b9ff:/# while [ $i -lt 1000 ]; do
>   echo "i is currently set to $i ....................................................................."
>   i=$(expr $i + 1)
> done
... (lots of output generated)
```

I can see the following in another window (run as root because /var/lib/docker is locked down):

```
# ls -al /var/lib/docker/containers/e6300962b9ffc21d5c8fec64a25ae2d66df0f8f36f69c7c5a674ec9aca697a75/*-json.log*
-rw-r----- 1 root root  336 Nov 22 09:49 /var/lib/docker/containers/e6300962b9ffc21d5c8fec64a25ae2d66df0f8f36f69c7c5a674ec9aca697a75/e6300962b9ffc21d5c8fec64a25ae2d66df0f8f36f69c7c5a674ec9aca697a75-json.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1007 Nov 22 09:49 /var/lib/docker/containers/e6300962b9ffc21d5c8fec64a25ae2d66df0f8f36f69c7c5a674ec9aca697a75/e6300962b9ffc21d5c8fec64a25ae2d66df0f8f36f69c7c5a674ec9aca697a75-json.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1006 Nov 22 09:49 /var/lib/docker/containers/e6300962b9ffc21d5c8fec64a25ae2d66df0f8f36f69c7c5a674ec9aca697a75/e6300962b9ffc21d5c8fec64a25ae2d66df0f8f36f69c7c5a674ec9aca697a75-json.log.2
```

You'll need to setup a different logfile rotation for the logs you are looking at, or reconsider whether you really need them at all and disable whatever is creating them.